# Como converter um nome inteiro normal para seu formato bibliográfico em c?

Tags: c, string

Eu quero saber como converter, por exemplo, a seguinte string:

"Barack Obama" para "OBAMA, Barack".

Ou seja, pro formato bibliográfico, tipo quando citam autores de livros/artigos.
Mas eu quero saber como converter qualquer tamanho de nome pra esse formato, pode ser com 2 nomes (como no exemplo acima) ou com 3, 4, 5... n nomes, por exemplo:

Lionel Andrés Blablabla Soccer Player Messi
Esse nome ficaria assim: MESSI, Lionel Andrés Blablabla Soccer Player.

Eu sei como converter se eu souber quantos nomes o nome inteiro da pessoa terá, mas eu quero saber como fazer isso pra qualquer tamanho de nome inteiro, ou seja, não necessitando saber quantos nomes a pessoa tem no nome inteiro.

Aqui está o código que eu consegui fazer até agora (ele funciona só para nomes inteiros que possuem 6 nomes no total):

```
char nome[30][100];
int i, j;

for(i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    scanf("%s", nome[i]);
for(j = 5; j > 4; j--)
    printf("%s,", strupr(nome[j]));
for(i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
    printf("%s ", nome[i]);
```

Comment: Uma dica: acredito que vc pode usar "strtok" para dividir o nome usando o espacos em branco.

Answer (score 2):

```
char* nome="Leonel da Silva Messi";

char* aux=strdup(nome);                // aux = cópia do nome
char* ue=strrchr (aux,' ');            // apontador para o ultimo espaço
*ue='\0';                              // aux = "Leonel da Silva\0Messi"
printf("%s, %s\n", ue+1, aux);         // ... ou strupr(ue+1) se estveres em MS
```